# Extract multi-year three month series (winter) from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, time-series

I've got a pandas DataFrame containing 70 years with hourly data, looking like this:

```
                                    pressure
2015-06-01 18:00:00                    945.6  
2015-06-01 19:00:00                    945.6  
2015-06-01 20:00:00                    945.4  
2015-06-01 21:00:00                    945.4  
2015-06-01 22:00:00                    945.3
```

I want to extract the winter months (D-J-F) from every year and generate a new DataFrame with a series of winters.
I found a lot of complicated stuff (e.g. extracting the `df.index.month` as a new column and then adress this one afterwards), but is there a way to get the winter months straightforward?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : [datetime.date(2015, 11, 1), datetime.date(2015, 12, 1), datetime.date(2015, 1, 1), datetime.date(2015, 2, 1)],
                   'pressure': [1,2,3,4]})
winter_months = [12, 1, 2]
print df

#          date  pressure
# 0  2015-11-01         1
# 1  2015-12-01         2
# 2  2015-01-01         3
# 3  2015-02-01         4

df = df[df["date"].map(lambda t: t.month in winter_months)]
print df

#          date  pressure
# 1  2015-12-01         2
# 2  2015-01-01         3
# 3  2015-02-01         4
```

**EDIT:** I noticed that in your example the dates are the dataframe's index. This still works:

```
df = df[df.index.map(lambda t: t.month in winter_months)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...the problem is that this method accesses the "regular" data columns and not the index.

Comment: I just edited my answer to show that it works on the index as well, just use `df.index.map(lambda t: t.month in winter_months)` instead.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wrote my comment while you were editing obviously....thanks! See also the answer I just found a second ago.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that

```
df[(df.index.month==12) | (df.index.month==1) | (df.index.month==2)]
```

works fine.